# Problems communicating by SPI from STM32F429 and ADE7878 board

Tags: spi, stm32f4

I'm trying to change the microcontroller that comes with the [ADE7878](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/eval-ade7878.html#eb-overview) evaluation board by the [STM32F429i](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1577/LN1806?ecmp=stm32f429-439_pron_pr-ces2014_nov2013&sc=stm32f429-439-pr). The documentation from Analog Devices shows how to do this using SPI. I'm trying it but I'm getting no response from ADE7878. I put some images to ilustrate the question:

[image]

[image: SCLk Signal in channel 1 and MOSI in channel 2]

[image: SS signal in channel 1 and MISO in channel 2]

And finally the problem:

[image: SCLK signal in channel 1 and MISO in channel 2]

As one can see, the MISO is oscillating in phase with clock but seams to be just a noise and everyting it sends is `0xFF`.

I am configuring SPI with this parameters:

```
SpiHandle.Instance               = SPIx;
SpiHandle.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_128;
SpiHandle.Init.Direction         = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
SpiHandle.Init.CLKPhase          = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
SpiHandle.Init.CLKPolarity       = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
SpiHandle.Init.CRCCalculation    = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
SpiHandle.Init.CRCPolynomial     = 7;
SpiHandle.Init.DataSize          = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
SpiHandle.Init.FirstBit          = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
SpiHandle.Init.NSS               = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
SpiHandle.Init.TIMode            = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
```

The clock of the STM32F429i is 180MHz.

I tested this STM32F429i SPI communication with another STM32F4 board and it was correct, with no problem, using this same configuration.

Please any question, any doubt let me know. It will be a pleasure to help you to help me... :)

Thanks!

Comment: The "noise" you see is probably due to the fast edges of the STM32 in combination with your probe setup. I notice you use SPI_NSS_SOFT in your init struct. This means the SPI chip select should be set by software, and is not set by hardware. Did you code and check the chip-select pin during SPI transfers?

Comment: @Hans I'm using an IO as Slave Select. See the edition with the SS signal. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any chance that the STM32F429 has burned the MISO output of ADE7878?? For example, draining more current than it could deliver?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that a digital isolator was burned. Exactly that one that sends the clock signal to the ADE7878.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mbed.org/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F429ZI/

If you use Ethernet and not SPI
Keep your board with the default configuration.
If you use SPI and not Ethernet
You should remove JP6 jumper on the front side of the board.
If you use both SPI and Ethernet
You have to patch the NUCLEO board on the back side: remove SB121 and close SB122 solder bridges. This will connect PB_5 to D11 instead of PA_7.